# Error con Random en JAVA

Tags: java

me aparece esta excepción, relacionada con el Random.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at gestorgrupos.Grupo.opcionAleatoria(Grupo.java:78)
    at gestorgrupos.Generador.generarListaOpciones(Generador.java:125)
    at principal.Principal.main(Principal.java:77)
```

Dejo a continuación el código donde está la generación del número aleatorio, a ver si alguien encuentra algún tipo de anomalía, me parece estar bien.

```
Random aleatoria = new Random();
 int i = aleatoria.nextInt(this.numGrupos);
```

--------------Añado el método----------------

```
public String generarListaOpciones() {

    String texto = "";

    Random aleatoria = new Random();
    int i = aleatoria.nextInt(this.numGrupos);
    int j = 1;
    IElegible opcionAleato;

    texto += "Orden de las opciones:";

    while (this.numGrupos > 0) {
        opcionAleato = this.grupos[i].opcionAleatoria();
        String mensaje = opcionAleato.opcion();

        texto += "nº" + j + " - Grupo: " + this.grupos[i].nombreCompleto() + "Opción: - "
                + this.grupos[i].opcionAleatoria().opcion() + mensaje;
        this.grupos[i].eliminaOpcion(opcionAleato);

        if (this.grupos[i].opciones.length == 0) {
            int posicionFinal = numGrupos-1;
            this.grupos[i] = this.grupos[posicionFinal];
            this.numGrupos--;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return texto;
}
```

------------------vista desde debugger-----------------------
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dice que le estás pasando un número negativo. Fíjate bien que no estés cogiendo un guión demás

Comment: Negativo o cero

Comment: El valor inicial de numGrupos es 20

Comment: Y no será que llamas dos veces a ese método? Entras con 20, sales con 0 (condición de salida del `while`)

Comment: No, lo llamo desde el main una sola vez

Comment: es otro método de la misma clase

Comment: si, hago otra llamada

Comment: El stacktrace lo dice claro, el error es al llamar a `nextint` en ese otro metodo. El problema como dijo @PabloLozano es que lo llamas con un numero negativo o 0, pero no en `generarListaOpciones` sino en `opcionAleatoria`

Comment: Acabo de hacer otra traza y en opcionAleatoria el número sigue siendo positivo

Comment: En cual de las numerosas veces que lo llamas? :)

Comment: El problema lo da, en generarListaOpciones, voy a hacer un par de trazas más, porque es ahí donde falla, a ver si ve lo pillo

Comment: Como veas, pero el stacktrace es muy muy claro:`at gestorgrupos.Grupo.opcionAleatoria(Grupo.java:78)`

Comment: @Pikoh, sí, era en opcionAleatoria, cuarta iteración, se quedaba a 0. Muchas gracias a tod@s

Answer (score 5):

[En la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-), como curiosidad, comenta explícitamente que el código de ese método es equivalente al siguiente:

```
public int nextInt(int bound) {
   if (bound <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("bound must be positive");

   if ((bound & -bound) == bound)  // i.e., bound is a power of 2
     return (int)((bound * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % bound;
   } while (bits - val + (bound-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }
```

Así que el problema es que `this.numGrupos` es un valor negativo o es cero, cuando debería ser mayor que cero.

Comment: No se quien ha dado el voto negativo pero esta respuesta es perfecta. Explica exactamente lo que se pregunta y demuestra el porque pasa.

Comment: Es curioso porque this.numGrupos está inicializada a un valor positivo.

Comment: Tendrás que ver con que valor llega cuando lo pasas como parámetro al método nextInt. Es posible que modifique su valor antes

Comment: Llega con valor 3, lo coge y peta.

Comment: Añado el método a la publicación: